# Convergence in $L^2( [0,T] \times \Omega )$ implies uniform convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $X^n$ be a family of continuous stochastic processes such that $E[ \sup_{t \in [0,T} \mid X^n_t \mid ^2 ] < \infty $ for all $n.$

We assume that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \int_0^T \mid X^n_t \mid^2 dt \right] = 0. $$

Doe this imply
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} E\left[ \sup_{t \in [0,T] } \mid X^n_t \mid^2 \right] = 0 \quad ?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Take $X_t^{n}(\omega) =t^{n}$ for all $n,t,\omega$ with $T=1$.